# Kohana 3 ORM - joins and has_many relationships with static methods

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana-3

I have Model_User which extends ORM, with a `$_has_many` relationship with roles:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'roles' => array('model'=>'role','through'=>'users_roles'),
);
```

I have a static function return all active users:

```
public static function get_all_active_users()
{
    return self::factory('user')->where('status', '=', 'active')->find_all();
}
```

I would like to update the function to return only users of a specific role, based on the following sql:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `users_roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` AND `roles`.`identifier` = 'admin'
WHERE `users`.`status` = 'active'
```

Is there a way to filter the results within the get_all_active_users method or should I create a new method and manually join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
return self::factory('user')
                ->join('users_roles', 'INNER')->on('users_roles.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
                ->join('roles', 'INNER')->on('roles.id', '=', 'users_roles.role_id')
                ->where(roles.identifier', '=', 'admin')
                ->where('status', '=', 'active')
                ->find_all();
```

Interested to know any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

A much more elegant way is defining the Role model to have many users like this:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
  'users' => array('model'=>'user','through'=>'users_roles'),
);
```

and then fetching the users through the Role itself like this:

```
return self::factory('role')
            ->where('identifier', '=', 'admin')
            ->users->
            ->where('status', '=', 'active')
            ->find_all();
```